# Error testing react components that contain react-toolbox components

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme, react-toolbox

I am trying to test some react components that contain some components from react toolbox, and when I import them in the test file, i get this error:

```
C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib\ripple\theme.scss:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @import "../colors";
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib\ripple\index.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib\button\index.js:22:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib\index.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/project/landscapp/App/src/modules/Core/input/labeledInput.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project\landscapp\App\src\modules\Core\input\index.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/project/landscapp/App/src/modules/Users/UserCard/components/accountSection.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/project/landscapp/App/test/spinner.spec.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:487:10)
    at loadAndRun (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:416:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project\landscapp\App\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:433:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Did someone else face this error and can someone help me?

Comment: Did you used? https://github.com/react-toolbox/toolbox-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this lines in my setup.js file in test folder:

```
function noop() {
  return null;
}

require.extensions['.css'] = noop;
require.extensions['.scss'] = noop;
require.extensions['.md'] = noop;
require.extensions['.png'] = noop;
require.extensions['.svg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.jpg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.jpeg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.gif'] = noop;
```